# asp.net debugging

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Have a website going live soon.  Have installed VS2008 on my prod server (temporarily) and wish to debug code when I access the actual prod web link.  In other words, I want to attached to the w3wp.exe service from w/in VS2008, then open a browser using the prod link of www.xyz.com - thus giving myself the ability to debug an actual prod call - instead of going through the \\localhost:0000.
I am on a Windows 2008R2 server and know VERY little about firewall settings for trying to access this remotely from my home PC...All past attempts have failed.
Thanx
Jerry

Answer (score 0):

If you have the studio installed on the production server just copy all the source code there, point IIS to the folder with your source code and it will be exactly like on your local machine.

If you get errors or other problems, please elaborate - "All past attempts have failed" is not really meaningful.

Comment: "All past attempts have failed" means that I have run the Remote Debugging config wizard, followed all of the instructions, 'played' w/different ports w/in the firewall - all w/no luck. Everything I've been told 'should' work, haven't yet...When you say, 'point IIS to the folder with your source code', I have my actual website name pointing to the folder under inetpub/wwwroot, if I want to use my www.xyz.com prod URL, are you saying I have to point that to my source code folder?   Thanx...Jerry

Comment: The remote debugging is meant for scenario where you don't have the whole source code and Studio on the remote server. In your case just log to the server with Remote Desktop and you're good to go..